# How to use where_in using Active Record Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to pass array to where_in using Active Record.

I saw few reference link, can pass like this:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', array('20','15','22','42','86'));
```

Query :

```
$mts = $this->db->select('subcat_id')->get_where('subcategory_tbl', array('cat_id' => $cat_id));
$result = $mts->result_array();
```

But My result Array in this form :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subcat_id] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subcat_id] => 13
        )
)
```

So how can i pass this array id to where_in clause ? I am confused here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
$this->db->where_in('cat_id', $cat_id)
$this->db->select('subcat_id');
$this->db->get('subcategory_tbl');
```

assuming that `$cat_id` contains the array of values to check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your result (array of rows) to an array of the values in the first "column" of those rows:

```
$ids = array_map(function($row) { return $row['subcat_id']; }, $result);
```

You probably should check $ids isn't empty before using it - since (I can't remember but I think) where_in will happily generate the invalid

`SELECT ... WHERE id IN ()`

if you pass it an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your first query like

```
$mts = $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(subcat_id) as new')->get_where('subcategory_tbl', array('cat_id' => $cat_id))->row()->new;
```

and then use

```
if($mts != "")
{
    $this->db->where_in('id',  $mts);
}
```

Hope it helps you....

Comment: wouldn't ->row()->subcat_id just get the *first* row's subcat_id?

Comment: @ShadowRadiance I am using `GROUP_CONCAT` here... :)

Comment: I missed the GROUP_CONCAT completely... wouldn't you have to still explode $mts to pass an array to where_in or will it handle a string like that?

Comment: Also... what happens if there are no matches... do you need a guard so that it doesn't generate "WHERE id IN ()" (technically would be a problem with my answer also... I'll make a note)

Comment: Yes `IN ()` also works like this `IN (x,y,z)`.... Yes he needs to make sure its not blank :)